# Execute dplyr operation only if column exists

Tags: r, function, dataframe, dplyr, lazy-evaluation

Drawing on the discussion on [conditional dplyr evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30604107/1655567) I would like conditionally execute a step in pipeline depending on whether the reference column exists in the passed data frame.

## Example

*The results generated by **`1)`** and **`2)`** should be identical.*

### Existing column

```
# 1)
mtcars %>% 
  filter(am == 1) %>%
  filter(cyl == 4)

# 2)
mtcars %>%
  filter(am == 1) %>%
  {
    if("cyl" %in% names(.)) filter(cyl == 4) else .
  }
```

### Unavailable column

```
# 1)
mtcars %>% 
  filter(am == 1)

# 2)    
mtcars %>%
  filter(am == 1) %>%
  {
    if("absent_column" %in% names(.)) filter(absent_column == 4) else .
  }
```

## Problem

For the available column the passed object does not correspond to the initial data frame. The original code returns the error message:

> Error in `filter(cyl == 4)` : object `'cyl'` not found

I have tried alternative syntax (with no luck):

```
>> mtcars %>%
...   filter(am == 1) %>%
...   {
...     if("cyl" %in% names(.)) filter(.$cyl == 4) else .
...   }
 Show Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error in UseMethod("filter_") : 
  no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "logical"
```

---

## Follow-up

I wanted to expand this question that would account for the evaluation on the right-hand side of the **`==`** in **`filter`** call. For instance the syntax below attempts to filter on the first available value. 
mtcars %>%

```
filter({
    if ("does_not_ex" %in% names(.))
      does_not_ex
    else
      NULL
  } == {
    if ("does_not_ex" %in% names(.))
      unique(.[['does_not_ex']])
    else
      NULL
  })
```

Expectedly, the call evaluates to an error message:

> Error in `filter_impl(.data, quo)` : Result must have length 32, not 0

When applied to existing column:

```
mtcars %>%
  filter({
    if ("mpg" %in% names(.))
      mpg
    else
      NULL
  } == {
    if ("mpg" %in% names(.))
      unique(.[['mpg']])
    else
      NULL
  })
```

It works with a warning message:

```
  mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.62 16.46  0  1    4    4
```

> Warning message: In `{` : longer object length is not a multiple of
>   shorter object length

### *Follow-up question*

*Is there a neat way of expending the existing syntax in order to get conditional evaluation on the right-hand side of the `filter` call, ideally staying within dplyr workflow?*

Comment: You just need another `.` as in `if("cyl" %in% names(.)) filter(., cyl == 4) else .` Here's a similar Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44001834

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## For dplyr version > 1.0.4

With `if_any` in dplyr > 1.0.4 you can achieve this:

```
mtcars %>% 
  select(!cyl) %>% 
  filter(am == 1) %>% 
  filter(if_any(matches("cyl"),  \(cl) cl == 4))
```

Or if you're using R < 4.1 you can use the old `purrr` style anonymous function `~.x ==4`:

```
mtcars %>% 
  select(!cyl) %>% 
  filter(am == 1) %>% 
  filter(if_any(matches("cyl"),  ~.x == 4))
```

See the [tidyverse blog](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2021/02/dplyr-1-0-4-if-any/#if_any-and-if_all) for more details.

## Old answer, for dplyr 1.0.0-1.0.7

This gives a deprecation warning in dplyr > 1.0.7

With `across()` in dplyr > 1.0.0 you can now use `any_of` when filtering. Compare original with all columns:

```
mtcars %>% 
  filter(am == 1) %>% 
  filter(cyl == 4)
```

With `cyl` removed, it throws an error:

```
mtcars %>% 
  select(!cyl) %>% 
  filter(am == 1) %>% 
  filter(cyl == 4)
```

Using `any_of` (note you have to write `"cyl"` and not `cyl`):

```
mtcars %>% 
  select(!cyl) %>% 
  filter(am == 1) %>% 
  filter(across(any_of("cyl"), ~.x == 4))
#N.B. this is equivalent to just filtering by `am == 1`.
```

Comment: This solution now gives a warning due to deprecation of using `across()` in `filter()`.  Could it be done with `if_any()`?

Comment: Thank you for highlighting this - I've updated the answer to include the `if_any` solution

Comment: The first solution here is much more readable with new anonymous functions (R >= 4.1 I think). One can write: `...filter(if_any(matches("cyl"),  \(cl) cl == 4))`

Comment: Thanks @jjj - I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 29):

Because of the way the scopes here work, you cannot access the dataframe from within your `if` statement. Fortunately, you don't need to.

Try:

```
mtcars %>%
  filter(am == 1) %>%
  filter({if("cyl" %in% names(.)) cyl else NULL} == 4)
```

Here you can use the '`.`' object within the conditional so you can check if the column exists and, if it exists, you can return the column to the `filter` function.

EDIT: as per docendo discimus' comment on the question, you can access the dataframe but not implicitly - i.e. you have to specifically reference it with `.`

Comment: re "you cannot access the dataframe from within your if statement." - that's not quite correct in my opinion; see my comment to the original post.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I meant implicitly but chose my words poorly. As you pointed out, you can use it by accessing `.`

Comment: This solution no longer works (try editing the string "cyl" to something that doesn't exist). The answer by Felipe Gerard does.

Answer (score 16):

I know I'm late to the party, but here's an answer somewhat more in line with what you were originally thinking:

```
mtcars %>%
  filter(am == 1) %>%
  {
    if("cyl" %in% names(.)) filter(., cyl == 4) else .
  }
```

Basically, you were missing the `.` in `filter`. Note this is because the pipeline doesn't add `.` to `filter(expr)` since it is in an expression surrounded by `{}`.

Comment: If you want to serially pipe to multiple code blocks, make sure that each connecting pipe (`%>%`) is on the same line as each ending `}` otherwise you'll get an `Error: unexpected SPECIAL in "  %>%"` error.

Answer (score 15):

### Avoid this trap:

On a busy day, one might do like the following:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(A = 1:3, B = letters[1:3], stringsAsFactors = F)
> df %>% mutate( C = ifelse("D" %in% colnames(.), D, B)) 
# Notice the values on "C" colum. No error thrown, but the logic and result is wrong
  A B C
1 1 a a
2 2 b a
3 3 c a
```

Why? Because `"D" %in% colnames(.)` returns only one value of `TRUE` or `FALSE`, and therefore `ifelse` operates only once. Then the value is broadcasted to the whole column!

### Correct way:

```
> df %>% mutate( C = if("D" %in% colnames(.)) D else B)
  A B C
1 1 a a
2 2 b b
3 3 c c
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed!  Also documenting that while ifelse() does the wrong thing silently, if_else() is "stricter" and will throw an error because it recognizes the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This code does the trick and is pretty flexible. The ^ and $ are regex used to perform an exact match.

```
mtcars %>% 
  set_names(names(.) %>% 
              str_replace("am","1") %>% 
              str_replace("^cyl$","2") %>% 
              str_replace("Doesn't Exist","3")
              )
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Unfortunately, this was too good to be true

I might be a bit late to the party.
But is

```
mtcars %>% 
 filter(am == 1) %>%
 try(filter(absent_column== 4))
```

a solution?

Comment: It does not appear to work running  `try(filter(cyl == 4))` returns unmodified data frame, where it should return object equivalent to applying `filter(cyl == 4)` as the **`cyl`** column exists.