# Remove column only if it exists

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to remove a column from a data frame only if it's there.

Example:

```
a <- 1:5
x <- tibble(a, b = a * 2, c = 1)
x %>% select(-'a')
x %>% select(-'d') # Throws an error
```

I want a way to remove columns `a` and `d` only if they exist, so `a` is removed and the attempt to remove `d` never happens. I tried modifying [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45146688/execute-dplyr-operation-only-if-column-exists) solution to my problem, but I could not get it to work.

Comment: Use `any_of()`: `x %>% select(-any_of(c('a', 'd')))`

Answer (score 1):

**data.table**

```r
library(data.table)
a <- 1:5
x <- data.frame(a, b = a * 2, c = 1)
cols <- c("a", "d")
my_cols <- intersect(cols, names(x))

setDT(x)[, ..my_cols]
#>    a
#> 1: 1
#> 2: 2
#> 3: 3
#> 4: 4
#> 5: 5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>