# Conditional filtering using tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I want to filter my data frame based on a variable that may or may not exist. As an expected output, I want a df that is filtered (if it has the filter variable), or the original, unfiltered df (if the variable is missing).

Here is a minimal example:

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- 
tribble(~a,~b,
        1L,"a",
        0L, "a",
        0L,"b",
        1L, "b")
df2 <- select(df1, b)
```

Filtering on `df1` returns the required result, a filtered tibble.

```
filter(df1, a == 1)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
      a     b
  <int> <chr>
1     1     a
2     1     b
```

But the second one throws an error (expectedly), as the variable is not in the df.

```
filter(df2, a == 1)
Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : 
  Evaluation error: object 'a' not found.
```

I tried `filter_at`, which would be an obvious choice, but it throws an error if there is no variable that matches the predicament.

```
filter_at(df2, vars(matches("a")), any_vars(. == 1L))    
Error: `.predicate` has no matching columns
```

So, my question is: is there a way to create a conditional filtering that produces the expected outcome, preferably within the tidyverse?

Comment: Isn't it better to have an error that suggests the column is not there?

Comment: I think this Q&A https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44001722/conditionally-apply-pipeline-step-depending-on-external-value should answer your question

Comment: What is the expected outcome?

Comment: How can you filter the data frame without given the right column?

Comment: For example (as in the linked Q), you can do stuff like `df2 %>% filter(if("a" %in% names(.)) a == 1 else TRUE)` or `df2 %>% {if("a" %in% names(.)) filter(., a == 1) else .}`

Comment: @JanvanderLaan OP wants the original data back if variable doesn't exist ("the original, unfiltered df (if the variable is missing). ")

Comment: can't you just wrap it in a `try` or `tryCatch` then ? or you want to be able to use it in pipe chains ?

Comment: @akrun Generally, you are right, but I want this for a data validation purpose, where the errors will be reported at a later phase

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As [@docendo-discimus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3521006/docendo-discimus) pointed out in the comments, the following solutions work. I also added `rlang::has_name` instead of `"a" %in% names(.)`.

This Q&A contains the original idea: [Conditionally apply pipeline step depending on external value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44001722/conditionally-apply-pipeline-step-depending-on-external-value).

```
df1 %>% 
   filter(if(has_name("a")) a == 1 else TRUE)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
      a     b
  <int> <chr>
1     1     a
2     1     b

df2 %>% 
   filter(if(has_name("a")) a == 1 else TRUE)
# A tibble: 4 x 1
      b
  <chr>
1     a
2     a
3     b
4     b
```

Or alternatively, by using `{}`:

```
df1 %>%
  {if(has_name("a")) filter(., a == 1L) else .} 
# A tibble: 2 x 2
      a     b
  <int> <chr>
1     1     a
2     1     b

> df2 %>%
+   {if(has_name("a")) filter(., a == 1L) else .}
# A tibble: 4 x 1
      b
  <chr>
1     a
2     a
3     b
4     b
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
# function for expected output
foo <- function(x, y){
  tmp <- which(colnames(x) %in% y)
  if(length(tmp) > 0){
    filter(x, select(x, tmp) == 1)
  }else{
    df1
  }
}

# run the functions
foo(df1, "a")
foo(df2, "a")
# or

df1 %>% foo("a")
# A tibble: 2 x 2
      a     b
  <int> <chr>
1     1     a
2     1     b

df2 %>% foo("a")
# A tibble: 4 x 2
      a     b
  <int> <chr>
1     1     a
2     0     a
3     0     b
4     1     b
```

Comment: Thanks, it is a fine answer, but I was looking for a tidyverse solution.